# Char (single letter) must be a pointer to correctly work?

Tags: c, xcode, string, pointers, char

I've searched and maybe this is not even an issue but while working with chars in C (I'm working with X-Code on Mac) I'm having problems dealing with them unless I used pointers

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    char myChar = "A";

    print("%c\n",myChar);
    print("%d\n",myChar);

    print("%c\n",65);
    print("%c\n",74);

    return 0;

}
```

So, simple stuff, but here's the output:

```
>J
>74

>A
>J
```

As you see, when I print `myChar` using %c, it gives me the lettre J and not A, same thing when I use %d, gives me 74 (char code for J) and not 65.

I also have a warning message on my variable declaration :

> *Incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing `char` with an expression of type `char[2]`"*

Which is kind of weird.

Now when replacing my code with this one :

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    char *myChar = "A";

    print("%c\n",*myChar);
    print("%d\n",*myChar);

    print("%c\n",65);
    print("%c\n",74);

    return 0;

}
```

The output is as expected :

```
>A
>65

>A
>J
```

Any idea on what this behavior is due? Did I miss something or do I fail to understand something?

Comment: `"a"` is a string (that is, a pointer). `'a'` is a character (that is, an `int`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code,

```
char myChar = "A";
```

is not correct. `"A"` is a *string literal*, which is not a fit for a `char`. You may want to write

```
 char myChar = 'A';
```

instead.

Note: Enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them.

Comment: Yes, that's it. The OP did get a warning, but couldn't make sense of it, probably because the warning mentions pointers and it isn't obvious to a beginner how pointers come in here.

Comment: @MOehm Right sir. :)

Comment: Thank you ! And no I did not understand the warning but besides that I think I understand how pointers work